# Error Number:2705,State:4,Class:16 Code first approach

Tags: sql, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

currently I'm using MYSQL 2019 (EF 3.1)and Visual Studio 2019 ASP . Net Core 3.1 version.

This is my model:

> ```
> public class User
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>
>     \[Required\]
>     public string Username { get; set; }
>     \[Required\]
>     public string Password { get; set; }
>     public string Email { get; set; }
>     public string Address { get; set; }
>    
>     \[Required\]
>     public DateTime  DateCreated { get; set; }
>     \[Required\]
>     public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
>     public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
>
> }
> ```
>
> I made a mistake, I didn't notice at the moment that I have two migrations for the same property(DateUpdated),and now I can't do new migration.
>
> This is my fourth migration:
>
> protected override void Up(Migration Builder migrationBuilder)
> {
> migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
> name: "DateUpdated",
> table: "MyBlog",
> nullable: true);
> }
>
> ```
>     protected override void Down(Migration Builder migration Builder)
>     {
>         migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
>             name: "DateUpdated",
>             table: "MyBlog");
>     }
> ```
>
> and тhis is my seventh migration:
>
> protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
> {
> migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
> name: "DateUpdated",
> table: "Users",
> nullable: false,
> defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));
>
> ```
>         migrationBuilder.AddColumn\<bool\>(
>             name: "IsAdmin",
>             table: "Users",
>             nullable: false,
>             defaultValue: false);
>     }
>
>     protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
>     {
>         migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
>             name: "DateUpdated",
>             table: "Users");
>
>         migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
>             name: "IsAdmin",
>             table: "Users");
>     }.
> ```

It gives me this error:

```
Error Number:2705,State:4,Class:16
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Date Updated' in table 'Users' is specified more than once.

I understand where my mistake is, but how can I solve this?
```